# How to keep Encryption Password inside of the application?

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-4.0

I have got some application that accepts a License encrypted key. So this application should keep inside `string encryptionPassword`  in order to decrypt that string and get some data.

Which is the best approach to keep `string encryptionPassword` inside of the application so if the user will try to hack it and it should be extremely difficult to do?

Any clue?

Thank you!!!

```
public static string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, string encryptionPassword)
{
            var algorithm = GetAlgorithm(encryptionPassword);

            byte[] encryptedBytes;
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
            {
                byte[] bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
                encryptedBytes = InMemoryCrypt(bytesToEncrypt, encryptor);
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}

public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string encryptionPassword)
{
            var algorithm = GetAlgorithm(encryptionPassword);

            byte[] descryptedBytes;
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(algorithm.Key, algorithm.IV))
            {
                byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
                descryptedBytes = InMemoryCrypt(encryptedBytes, decryptor);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(descryptedBytes);
}
```

Comment: A determined enough user will manage to read such a password - it can take time and effort, but it will be possible.

Comment: Also - see [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).

Comment: @Oded Than you! But I cannot use .NET 4.5

Comment: `SecureString` has been around since .NET 2.0 - there is a dropdown for the version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) may fit the bill:

> Represents text that should be kept confidential. The text is encrypted for privacy when being used, and deleted from computer memory when no longer needed.

Also:

> A `SecureString` object is similar to a `String` object in that it has a text value. However, the value of a `SecureString` object is automatically encrypted, can be modified until your application marks it as read-only, and can be deleted from computer memory by either your application or the .NET Framework garbage collector.

And

> The value of an instance of `SecureString` is automatically encrypted when the instance is initialized or when the value is modified. Your application can render the instance immutable and prevent further modification by invoking the `MakeReadOnly` method.

Note, however, that aA determined enough user will manage to read such a password - it can take time and effort, but it will be possible

Comment: Cool. But I am planning to keep `string encryptionPassword` like hard-coded forever. So I've guessed to use some static array to keep chars of it and etc... So when application can detect that there is a new License string it should decrypt it automatically...

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to storing a key so as to prevent hacking is: **You don't**.

See [this article](http://www.brandonstaggs.com/2007/07/26/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system-in-delphi/) for an alternative.

> The solution is called a Partial Key Verification System because your software never tests the full key. Since your application does not include the code to test every portion of the key, it is impossible for a cracker to build a working valid key generator just by disassembling your executable code.
>
> This system is not a way to prevent cracks entirely. It will still be possible for a cracker to edit your executable to jump over verification code. But such cracks only work on one specific release, and I’ll suggest a couple of tricks to make their job harder to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Secure String. It automatically encrypts the string Value in memory.